# Why won't the hyperlink work in asp.net gridview first few rows

Tags: html, asp.net

I have an asp.net gridview table. There is an email column that contains emails. The first few rows (depending on the browser) the hyperlink mailto does not allow you to click on the link.
Below is my code for the gridview

```
enter code here
<asp:GridView ID="grd_Directory" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnPageIndexChanging="grd_Directory_OnPageIndexChanging" OnSorting="grd_Directory_Sorting" AutoGenerateColumns="False"
                        BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="3" DataKeyNames="Account" ShowFooter="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="OnSelectedIndexChanged"
                        PageSize="200" CssClass="Grid" HeaderStyle-CssClass="GVFixedHeader">
                        <RowStyle Height="20px" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:TemplateField>
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <asp:Button ID="btnPopup" runat="server" Text="View" OnClick="btnPopup_Click" CssClass="btn btn-primary py-3 px-5" />
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Account" HeaderText="User Login" SortExpression="Account" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" SortExpression="FirstName" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" SortExpression="LastName" />
                           
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText =" Work Phone">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                    <a href="CLICKTOCALL:<%# Eval ("WorkPhone") %>"><%# Eval ("WorkPhone") %></a>
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Extension" HeaderText="Extension" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="CellPhone" HeaderText="Cell Phone" />
                        
                            <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Email">
                                <ItemTemplate>
                                     <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ata-toggle="tooltip" title="Click Here To Email!" Text='<%# Eval("Email") %>' NavigateUrl='<%# string.Format("mailto:{0}", Eval("Email"))%>' />
                                   
                                </ItemTemplate>
                            </asp:TemplateField>
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Office" HeaderText="Office" SortExpression="Office" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Department" HeaderText="Department" SortExpression="Department" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Title" HeaderText="Title" SortExpression="Title" />
                            <asp:BoundField ItemStyle-Width="150px" DataField="Supervisor" HeaderText="Supervisor" SortExpression="Supervisor" />
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="ID" />
                        </Columns>
                    </asp:GridView>
enter code here
```

Comment: You have to inspect the web page - try chrome and hit f12, or even the newer chrome based Edge explore from MS. I suspect that some "div" from above has some strange margin and is not allowing any clicks - lets alone the hyper links. However, using browser debug tools and using elements and then clicking on a hyper link will often show or give you an idea of what is going wrong here. When you inspect using the browser, can you see the hyper-link values and do they look correct?

Comment: I have ran the debugger in Chrome and Edge and I didn't see any issues. I also looked at the divs in the section of the table and removed any CSS classes that might cause the issue but still has not fixed the issue. I don't know what could be causing the issue.

Comment: When I an at the  20 inch screen the first 5 rows the navigation link does not work.  When I go to a 16 inch screen the links work.

Comment: and on the screens that don't work, when you put the browser into developer mode, select elements and then click on the hyper link, what does the browser show? In this mode no hyper-links will work but you be able to see what element on the screen is being selected - including say some "div" or other object that is covering over the hyper-link or preventing them from working. So what do the developer tools and element in the browser tools show when you do this? it should show what the browser is seeing and if the link is going to work or often show why the click and link does not